# How to return an Immutable object from a factory function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

I have a basic function accepts Temperature data as an argument and  then perform a simple temperature conversion operation on the data
How can we perform the same functionality using without mutating the object? i.e, the function should not mutate the argument passed in, it should rather return a copy

```
 function temperature(args) {
    convertToF = convertToC = temperatureConverter
    return Object.assign({
        args,
        convertToF,
        convertToC
    }, w.weatherData(args))
}
```

I have some helper functions to help with conversion

```
 function temperatureConverter(args) {
        const bool = args.unit === 'F'
        return (bool) ? self.Celsiusconverter(args) : self.fahrenheitConverter(args)
    }

    function Celsiusconverter(args) {
        args.value = (args.value - 32) * (5 / 9)
        args.unit = 'C'
        return {
            ...args
        }
    }

     function fahrenheitConverter(args) {
        args.value = (args.value * 9 / 5 + 32)
        args.unit = 'F'
        return {
            ...args
        }
    }
```

the args object looks like so :

```
const objTemp1 = {
    unit: 'C',
    type: 'Temp',
    date: '2010-04-20T00:00:00.000Z',
    place: 'someCity',
    value: 10,
}
```

Comment: Don’t assign back to the original object.. create. shallow alone first, or use explicit properties after so there is no “encouragement” to use `args.value = ..` on the original.

Comment: do you have an example about how I will not assign to the original object?

Comment: `newArgs = { ...args }; newArgs.value = ..` would be an implementation that first creates a shallow clone.

Comment: do you mean in the temperatureConverter helper function ?

Comment: Could also use a merge with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) - `return {...args, { value = .. }}`, such that the original object (args) is *not modified*.

Comment: do you mean like this:                                                                                                                            function temperatureConverter(args) {                                                                                                                                        
     newArgs = {...args}
        const bool = newArgs.unit === 'F'
        return (bool) ? self.Celsiusconverter(newArgs) : self.fahrenheitConverter(newArgs)
    }

Comment: I would place it *in the individual function(s) that incorrectly causes the mutations*.

Comment: so in all the functions that are responsible for mutating the args Celsiusconverter and fahrenheitConverter, did I get what you mean correctly ?

Comment: Yes - that’s where I would ensure the mutation is avoided / does not start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the functions will look like this, and that solves the issue

```
function temperatureConverter(args) {
        const bool = newArgs.unit === 'F'
        return (bool) ? self.Celsiusconverter(args) : self.fahrenheitConverter(args)
    }

    function Celsiusconverter(args) {
        newArgs = {...args}
        newArgs.value = (newArgs.value - 32) * (5 / 9)
        newArgs.unit = 'C'
                return newArgs

    }

     function fahrenheitConverter(args) {
        newArgs = {...args}
        newArgs.value = (newArgs.value * 9 / 5 + 32)
        newArgs.unit = 'F'
                return newArgs

    }
```

Comment: Just `return newArgs` (it’s already a copy); should also be `args` still in the main dispatch function.

Comment: what if I want to return a new factory function in the temperature(args)            convertToF = convertToC = () => self.temperature([...args]).map((x)=> util.temperatureConverter(x))

Comment: this will return  args is not iterable, how can I come around this

Comment: Fadi - Sure, if written correctly. However, `[...args]` is wrong (spread in array literal) and it should be `{...args}` (spread in object literal), as elsewhere.

Comment: unfortunately, this {...args} did not work it says {(intermediate value)}.map is not a function